# add a color to eyes in my dog model

Tags: materials, uv, texture-painting

I already have a dog texture image and is placed on the dog model but I want to color one of the eyelids of dog to greenish
[image]

[image]

what I want to achieve is this like one of the eyes should be green like that
[image]

Comment: Can't you just edit the image texture in an image manipulation program (like GIMP or Krita or Photoshop)?

Comment: Add a HSV Node between the Image Texture and the Shader Node and adjust the Hue. If you want different color for each eye, duplicate the material and assign one for the left and one for the right. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/hue_saturation.html

Comment: @haarigertroll yeah lol I realized that right after posting the question I edit it on photoshop thanks

Comment: @FFeller I will sure try that too